# Sorting a part of a coordinate

Tags: sorting

I've got a question regarding sorting. These are the coordinates that have to be sorted:

```
{{m, 7}, {z, 1}, {x, 4}, {b, 8}, {t, 2}, {f, 9}}
```

But only the first part of the coordinates have to be sorted (in ascending order). What command(s) do I use for this?

Comment: Simply [`Sort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "first part" Do you want them to be sorted with respect to the first variable in the list? Do you want only subset to be sorted?

Comment: With respect to the first variable. Basically this: 
Sort[{{a, 2}, {c, 1}, {d, 3}}, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &]   I did apply this code to my coordinates to sort with respect to the second variable. But I don't really understand the #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] & part hence why I can't apply it

Comment: `Sort` by default sorts with respect to the first element. `Sort` of your list is `{{b, 8}, {f, 9}, {m, 7}, {t, 2}, {x, 4}, {z, 1}}` - is this what you want?

Comment: As pointed out by @corey979, the default for `Sort` is to sort by first element. However, if you want to make your code more explicit, you could use `Sort[data, OrderedQ[{#1,#2}]&]` (Note: that inequality comparisons only evaluate to True/False for numeric values which is why they worked for the second elements but not the first) or more simply use `SortBy[data, First]`

Answer (score 1):

Unsurprisingly, `Sort` is for sorting. For numeric 1D inputs (not necessarily integers, also reals, and with repetitions):

```
Sort[{7, 1, 4, 8, 2, 9}]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9}

It works also for characters, according to lexicographical order:

```
Sort[{m, z, x, b, t, f}]
```

> {b, f, m, t, x, z}

In case when numbers are mixed with characters, numbers come first:

```
Sort[{m, z, x, b, t, f, 7, 1, 4, 8, 2, 9}]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, b, f, m, t, x, z}

`Sort` accepts also a second arguments allowing to specify a function for the sorting. For example, when one has 2D data

```
data = {{8, 9}, {5, 3}, {3, 0}, {1, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 7}, {5, 5}, {9, 3}}
```

the default setting is to sort according to the first element in each pair:

```
Sort[data]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 0}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}, {9, 3}}

To sort according to the second element, one needs to specify the ordering function:

```
Sort[data, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &]
```

> {{3, 0}, {1, 2}, {9, 3}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}}

The same technique can be used to sort in descending order, e.g.

```
Sort[{7, 1, 4, 8, 2, 9}, #1 > #2 &]
```

> {9, 8, 7, 4, 2, 1}

(which, by the way, is of course the same as `Reverse[Sort[{7, 1, 4, 8, 2, 9}]]`).

The second argument of `Sort` allows to sort, e.g., according to the absolute value:

```
Sort[{-1, -2, -3, -4, 1, 2, 3, 4}, Abs[#1] < Abs[#2] &]
```

> {1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4}

`Sort` on `data` works according to canonical order:

```
Sort[dat, OrderedQ[{#1, #2}] &]
```

> {{b, 8}, {f, 9}, {m, 7}, {t, 2}, {x, 4}, {z, 1}}

To `Sort` in reverse order (still according to the first element):

```
Sort[dat, OrderedQ[{#2, #1}] &]
```

> {{z, 1}, {x, 4}, {t, 2}, {m, 7}, {f, 9}, {b, 8}}

`Sort` in reverse order according to the second element:

```
Sort[dat, OrderedQ[{#2[[2]], #1[[2]]}] &]
```

> {{f, 9}, {b, 8}, {m, 7}, {x, 4}, {t, 2}, {z, 1}}

---

`SortBy` might be another option. E.g., to sort according to the last element:

```
SortBy[data, Last]
```

> {{3, 0}, {1, 2}, {5, 3}, {9, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}}

or according to differences between elements of each pair:

```
SortBy[data, Differences]
```

> {{9, 3}, {3, 0}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {1, 2}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}}

To complete the last example:

```
Differences /@ data
```

> {{1}, {-2}, {-3}, {1}, {-1}, {1}, {0}, {-6}}